# Pad single-digit numbers with a zero

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I have a loop like this to save sheets as CSV files but my first 9 sheets are name liked `sinani-01 ... sinani-09` (not like `sinani-1 ... sinani-9`). How I can concatenate a `0` *only* before numbers less than 10?

```
Sub Adder()
    Dim animal As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 120
        animal = "sinani-" & i
        Sheets(animal).SaveAs "E:\Data\CSV\" & animal & ".csv", xlCSV
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

VBA has a `Format()` function that you can use to pad numbers.

```
animal = "sinani-" & Format$(i, "00")
```

This will pad single-digit numbers with a `0`. Your two- and three-digit numbers will continue to work as expected.

Answer (score 9):

In the fifth line use the Format function like this:

```
animal = "sinani-" & Format(i, "#00")
```

The `#` means optionally a digit (i.e. present only if there are that many digits in `i`), `0` means definitely a digit, whereby leading zeros are used if `i` hasn't got enough digits.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate with a leading series of zeroes and peel off as many digits from the right-hand side as you need.

```
animal = "sinani-" & Right("00" & i, 2)

'alternate for many leading zeroes (e.g. DUNS number)
animal = "sinani-" & Right(String(9, "0") & i, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `& i` by `& IIF(i < 10,"0","") & i`

On edit: Even though in this case `Format` provides a cleaner solution than `IIF`, the `IIF` trick has some other uses in tweaking output. For example, if you wanted to inform the user how many cells were found which satisfy some condition you could use something like

```
MsgBox n & "cell" & IIF(n <> 1,"s","") & " found"
```

to gracefully handle plural vs. singular endings